# Shell script variable not used

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having some issues with a shell script that I've written in order to loop over some files. My filenames are labeled in a ordered fashion so I can use a couple of loops to run all of my tests.

The example file that I'm calling inside the loop is a executable that takes the file name as input argument (that works). I'm trying to construct a script that can run all the files and gather the execution time (the gathering part is not displayed here).

```
for ((N = 1; N<=10; N++)); do
FILE=N${N}_L${L}_US${US}_th${th}_C${C}_q${q}_exp${exp}_kmn${kmn}_kmx${kmx}_mu${mu}_mxrej${mxrej}_p$(bc <<< "scale=1; $k/10")
./example $FILE
done
```

echo gives following, which is the way I want it to look.

```
echo $FILE
N1_L1_US200_th1_C5_q1_exp-2_kmn3_kmx150_mu0.1_mxrej100_p.1
N2_L1_US200_th1_C5_q1_exp-2_kmn3_kmx150_mu0.1_mxrej100_p.1
N3_L1_US200_th1_C5_q1_exp-2_kmn3_kmx150_mu0.1_mxrej100_p.1
.
.
.
```

When running the full loop passing the argument $FILE to ./example executable I get a error from the executable saying that there is no file called "$FILE".

Comment: It's not clear what is the shell script that you are trying to run. The code that was posted has no loops. Also, why do you quote the 'example' lines ? What is the problem that you are trying to solve ? Please post a script that can reproduce the probem.

Comment: So is there a single script named `example`, or do you have multiple scripts named `example N8_L3_USa_thx...`, etc.? Your claim that `./example" "$FILE` gives the correct output suggests the latter, in which case that's what you have to do (though it's more conventionally written `./"example $FILE"`).

Comment: @dash-o  I realize that it was a bit unclear, I've changed it up a bit, hope that this explains my issue better.

Comment: Please change `./example $FILE` to `echo ./example $FILE` to see what the shell is trying to execute.

Comment: Are the files in the same directory as the script?

Comment: @AlexP .looks as it should but when running  with echo in front, but when running the executable I get (core dumped) ./example $file_name.

Comment: @UlisesAndréFierro The executable is but the data is in another directory but its mapped correctly inside the C++ code. When running straight from terminal everything works as should (the executable that is).

Comment: @SinaMohammadi We assume that our programs just do what we do in the shell but that's not the case. Please try the same using the full path to the files, just prepend your $FILE variable with the path to the files and let me know what happens.

Comment: Can you clarify the error is it `(core dumped) ./example $file_name,` or ` there is no file called "$FILE". Whey you t put $FILE, do you mean the literal '$FILE', or the actual file name ?

Comment: @UlisesAndréFierro I tried that if I understood correctly, instead of using the variable I just put the path to one file instead. Since I'm on a deadline I already started doing that. But I really think that this shouldn't be necessary..

Comment: @dash-o No I mean the literal like as if i copy it from terminal with no modification that's the error it gives me. Where I believe that it should give the information stored inside the variable as in the case when I use echo.

Comment: Suggest you post MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)